# Avoid type casting for subclasses

Tags: java

I have two classes that inherit from the same class:

```java
ClientUserManager extends UserManager
```

and

```java
ServerUserManager extends UserManager
```

UserManager is abstract.

```java
public abstract class UserManager {

    protected final UserService userService;

    public UserManager(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }
```

As an example, the server subclass:

```java
public class ServerUserManager extends UserManager {

    public ServerUserManager(UserService userService) {
        super(userService);
    }

    public void someMethod() {
        ((ServerUserSerivice)userService).doSomethingForSERVERONLY();
    }
```

However, my sub-classes should each be able to use their specializations of `UserService` (`ClientUserService` or `ServerUserService`), as you can already see from `someMethod()`. I would like to be able to do without the constant typecasting.

Is there a more elegant or generic solution?

> Side info: To justify why I want to both generalize things and keep
> specializations at the same time (as Oğuzhan Aslan already pointed
> out), let me say that I use a dependency injection framework (Dagger
> 2)  which gives me for the same "key"/superclass, the respective
> implementation in return (here client or server).

Comment: It seems to me that you are trying to generalize the classes but also support the details of the subclasses. From my personal experience, this is not feasible and yet not easy thing to do without typecasting. I think if they do not have a common thing to do you should use their own interface i.e ServiceUM should take a ServerUserService.

Comment: I still don't understand. Why can't you just `public ServerUserManager(ServerUserService sus)` ? A DI framework should be able to work with that.

Comment: The problem is that I keep `userService`:UserService as a field in the super class, so I always have to type cast it in the sub-classes. Of course, I could also keep a reference to the same object in the subs from type `ServerUserService` or `ClientUserService`, but that would be redundant. So the parent class would manage the same reference just of a different type. For the methods in the parent/super class, I would consider userService; I would keep the sub-service version in the sub/child class. At the end both would be references to the same object, just of different types.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use generics:

```java
public abstract class UserManager<T extends UserService> {

    protected final T userService;

    public UserManager(T userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }
}

public class ServerUserManager extends UserManager<ServerUserService> {

    public ServerUserManager(ServerUserService userService) {
        super(userService);
    }

    public void someMethod() {
        userService.doSomethingForSERVERONLY();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely clear what you are trying to achieve but I will suggest in general to try and use design patterns according to your use case.

This one seems similar to a "Strategy Pattern".
You have a context (UserManager) that should get some specific strategy (UserService) and use it.

For example:

```
public interface UserService {    
    public void execute(); 
}

public class ServerUserService implements UserService {
    public void execute(){
       //does something for server    
    }; 
}

class ServerUserManager {
    private UserService userService;
 
    public ServerUserManager(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }
 
    public void doSomething() {
        return this.userService.execute();
    }
};
```

You can google "Strategy Pattern" to see different flavours of implementation